# What is the best practice for building choices list

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form with a choice type element. I need to populate it with data. As I know there are 3 methods.

**1. Controller:**

```
// Controller
public function myAction()
{
      $choices = ...; // create choices array
      $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType($dm), null, array(
            'choices' => $choices,
        ));
}

// Form
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('cars', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $options['choices']
        ));
    }
}
```

**2. Form class + repository**

```
// Controller
public function myAction()
{
      $dm = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
      $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType($dm));
}

// Form
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $dm;

    public function __construct($dm) 
    {
        $this->dm = $dm;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('cars', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $options['choices']
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $list = array();
        foreach($this->dm->getRepository('MyBundle:Cars')->findAll() as $car) {
            $list[$car->getName()] = $car->getName();
        }

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'choices'        => $list,
        ));
    }
}
```

**3. Form class + custom service**

```
// Controller
public function myAction()
{
      $dm = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
      $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), null, array(
            'myservice' => $this->get('myservice'),
        ));
}

// Form
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('cars', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $options['myservice']->getCars()
        ));
    }
}

// Service
class MyService
{
    const ENTITY_CAR = 'MyBundle:Cars';

    /** @var DocumentManager */
    private $dm;

    public function __construct(DocumentManager $dm)
    {
        $this->dm = $dm;
    }

    public function getCars()
    {
        return $this->dm->getRepository("MyBundle:Cars")->findAll();
    }
}
```

I'll express my thoughts.

The 1st option is not the best practice. Especially when complicated logic is involved. Controllers should be as tiny as possible.

The 2nd is much better. But it exposes entity name and problems may occur if I decide to rename it.

The 3rd is the best option, imho. Entity names are concentrated in one place, better IDE type hinting, centralized entity management (search, save, remove...). The main disadvantage is a possible over-engineered class as it's becoming responsible for many read/write operations. On the other hand it can be divided into pieces.

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third option is good if you have to reuse that service elsewhere in your code (and if that service will grown in comparison of that you've wrote, we'll see it later). In that way, as you said, "manager" of that entity is one and contains itself the name of repo,a const, and so on.

## **BUT**

If this service is use only as a "pusher" for reach your repository by hiding its name, I don't think that this solution is still much good as it seems.
Obviously if that service is thought for have multiple persistance options and multiple retrieve option (base on what ORM you've selected), in that case this could be the best practice.

In other cases, I suppose that the second one is always the better.

The first isn't practicable unless you want to ignore all good practices

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a fourth solution : use an `entity` field as it is designed to be a choice field with options loaded from DB !

Here is the official doc http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html

And how you may use it :

```
// Form
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('cars', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyBundle:Cars',
            'property' => 'name',
            //Optionnal if you need to condition the selection
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
            },
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: In case of this solution I can't set values for options list. The property _name_ defines labels only and indexes are used as values that it's not suitable for me.

Comment: What do you need as value and text for your options ?